# Thin cannot require sinatra contrib gem

Tags: ruby, sinatra, thin

My app.rb file header is:

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'sinatra/multi_route'
```

Config.ru:

```
require './app'
run Sinatra::Application
```

When running with the command:

```
thin -R config.ru start
```

it raises error:

```
`require': cannot load such file -- sinatra/multi_route (LoadError)
```

but if i call ruby app.rb, it works fine. Actually thin also works fine on my MacOSX, but thin on linux(Ubuntu 12.0.4). Any thing strange with thin on linux?

Thin's version i used is: 1.6.0, 1.5.1, all failed

Comment: You can use `rackup` command and it will use thin if it is installed.

Comment: Do you have `sinatra-contrib` in you `Gemfile`? And if yes, do you have it in version which contains `multi_route`?

Comment: I don't use Gemfile to manage gems. And i have install sinatra-contrib. Everything works fine on my mac but not linux. Thanks for reply